# Storm with SQS and Cassandra insert happenning more than once

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-storm, amazon-sqs

I have been recently trying out Apache Storm in AWS. I created an SQS spout which reads from SQS and passes to a Cassandra bolt to be inserted to db.
When the db insert succeeds the acknowledgement is sent back and message is deleted from SQS. But when parallelism hint is increased a message is inserted more than once. Probably because another thread already read the same message from SQS before the acknowledgement reached back to spout. How can I handle this situation? Without parallelism the speed is quite slow.

Comment: I am not familiar with SQS, but you need to "block" reading the data twice (is there anything like an offset as in Apacha Kafka you could use?). Or you can set a global "flag". This "blocking" flag should be deleted when the message is either fully processed (together with the message itself) or when the message fails within Storm (ie, just delete the flag to allow reading the message again). If SQS does not give you any support for this, you need a (scalable) distributed synchronization mechanism for your spouts (ie, distributed hash-table or similar)

Answer (score 0):

You can just increase the visibility timeout property in Amazon SQS. So it will not visible to other thread until the timeout exceed, after taking the job by one thread.

Check following video for more info.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxnuioFAxac